# TFS2017 When the old builds/releases are purged

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We started one month ago to heavily use the Release Management part of TFS and I noticed that the collection's database size is increasing with an accelerate rate.

In order to stabilize the database size growth we're adjusting the retention policies of the release definitions.

Do you know when the purging process of the deleted builds/releases is occurring?
Can be manually triggered?

TFS v15.117.26714.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 11/03**
[image]

*When you change the **Permanently Destroy Releases** in Retention Policy Settings page, after save changes, it will prompt:*

> Changes to the settings will be **effective only for the new Release
>   Definitions and Environments created after the save.**

So it will not influence your old deleted release, afraid the old deleted release will keep 30 days(default setting) when it created. You may have to wait.

---

**Update**

When you  delete a build through the retention policy, however this is only a **logical delete** and the records remain in the database but are flagged with a delete flag.

The **Destroy** command will physically delete the build from the system, it will be completely gone and all records will be removed from the DB.

TFS  will not recover the space straight away,  which is deleted later by a job ran by the **[TFS Background Job Agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2013/02/12/tfs2012-what-are-all-the-different-jobs-built-in-to-tfs/)**. The TFSJob Agent will recover the space during its normal running process so you may not see the space recovered for 24 hrs +.

If you don’t want to wait that much, you can run tf destroy with the `/startcleanup` switch which immediately kicks off the cleanup job.

---

> **When are builds deleted**
>
> *TFS*: Your retention policies run every day at 3:00 A.M. UTC. **There is no option to change this process**.
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention#build-retention)*

It's not able to manually  trigger the purging process of the deleted builds/releases in TFS for now.

Note builds that are deployed as part of releases are also **governed** by the release retention policy.  The build linked to a release has its own retention policy, which may be shorter than that of the release.

If you want to retain the build for the same period as the release, set the **Retain** build checkbox for the appropriate environments. This overrides the retention policy for the build, and ensures that the artifacts are available if you need to redeploy that release.

When you delete a release definition, delete a release, or **when the retention policy deletes a release automatically**, the retention policy for the associated build will determine when that build is deleted.

Comment: I'm interested in when the builds/releases marked as "deleted" are removed from database

Comment: @ds19 Yes when you  delete a build through the retention policy, however this is only a **logical delete** and the records remain in the database but are flagged with a delete flag. You may need the destroy option,  TFS  will not recover the space straight away,  which is deleted later by a job ran by the **[TFS Background Job Agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2013/02/12/tfs2012-what-are-all-the-different-jobs-built-in-to-tfs/)**.  If you don’t want to wait that much, you can run tf destroy with the `/startcleanup` switch which immediately kicks off the cleanup job.See my update.

Comment: Can be used the TfsBuild tool to destroy vNext builds? According with this forum [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92b7b11b-b744-4dba-a160-e446eb3fad81/tfsbuildexe-standard-output?forum=tfsbuild) the tool is only for XAML builds.

Comment: @ds19 Yes, this is not able to work with vNext builds. For vNext builds / release  which is also managed by retention policy,  **the destruction policy** (
Days to keep build record after deletion) helps you keep the builds/releases for a certain period of time after they are deleted. This policy cannot be overridden in individual build/release definitions. If you want to change this, you need to change **global build retention policy** (default is 30 days), for TFS2017: `https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue`

Comment: @ds19 It's same with Global release retention policy, the address is `https://{your_server}/tfs/{collection_name}/{team_project}/_admin/_apps/hub/ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-project-admin-hub`

Comment: Hi @ds19 Any update on this, have you figured it out follow above suggestion? Any questions please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Even I've set the destruction policy of the releases to 1 day (through `http://tfs:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/Default/_admin/_release`, Days to keep releases after deletion=1) I still can see deleted releases from October 11th.

Comment: Hi@ds19,  What's the number of "`minimum number of releases`" in your configuration. The retention timer on a release is reset every time a release is modified or deployed to an environment. **The minimum number or releases to retain setting takes precedence over the number of days.**  For example, if you specify to retain a minimum of three releases, **the most recent three will be retained indefinitely** - irrespective of the number of days specified. However, you can manually delete these releases when you no longer require them. This maybe the root cause.

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT,
The problem is with the deleted builds/releases that are not destroyed/purged from database; even the setting is set to 1 day there are releases "marked" as deleted from one week. The `minimum number of releases` shouldn't influence the purge of a deleted release.

Comment: @ds19 I couldn't see my old deleted release in the web portal. Will test this phenomenon here in my environment  this weekend, any update  let you know ASAP.

Comment: Hi @ds19 I could reproduce your situation. This is due to  changes to the settings will be **effective only for the new Release
 Definitions and Environments created after the save.**  It will not influence the old deleted release. I have created a clean new release and deleted it after saving the setting, it  destroyed as expected.  Details please see my update answer.

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT, So if I have a release definition that was created when the setting was the default value (14 days) and after 1 month I changed the setting to 1 day then all releases (regardless when they were created) will be destroyed after 14 days. What happens if I delete the release definition? The releases are destroyed and the space is released?

Comment: Hi @ds19 Haven't try this, but guess not. Sounds like a little unreasonable, if you could be able to recover  a deleted release definition, then you should also be able to recover the deleted releases of the definition. If delete a release definition will destroy all releases under it. It doesn't make sense, I'm afraid the release will still be destroyed and the space is released after 14 days.